# How to export module properly so vscode can show my module in suggestion [ctrl+space]?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have a setting style file like:

`GlobalStyles.js`

```
export const GlobalStyles={
  ViewContainer:{flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'},
  Center:{justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'},
  FontNormal:15,
  FontMedium:18,
  FontLarge:28,
  FontHeader:38
}

module.export={GlobalStyles}
```

and when i used it in another JS file, let say `Home.js`. i want to vscode know every `Key:Value` i've defined,

with those export in `GlobalStyles.js` vscode suggesting an import style like this:

```
import { GlobalStyles } from '../Component/GlobalStyles';
```

and my expected result is something like:

```
import { ViewContainer, Center, FontMedium, [and so on]} from '../Component/GlobalStyles';
```

how to let vscode suggesting me *Auto Import foo from path/to/GlobalStyles* when i'm typing **foo**? where `foo` is like `ViewContainer, Center, FontMedium, [and so on]`.

Comment: What object is there that matches the keyword `foo` that you are typing?

Comment: @ifconfig all key:value inside GlobalStyles, like Center, FontMedium, etc

Answer (score 4):

The feature you're talking about is called [Auto Imports](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_auto-imports). To answer your question, this feature exists and works by default in VSCode.

Here is a sample of how i've used it in a React project. Here I have a component inside a folder with the same name. Outside of that folder is a file I called ModuleExports.js and it currently has the following code.

```
import Navbar from "./Navbar/Navbar";

export { Navbar };
```

For reference, export is an alias of module.export so feel free to use them interchangeably. This is a component so when I try to use it as such you can see from the screenshot I am suggested an import to use.

[image: example import suggestion 1]

The same can be done without being a component. I'll declare a testObject inside the same file ModuleExports.js and export it.

[image: create a testObject]

Then let's see if intellisense will pick it up.

[image: it works]

There it is. I hope this helps and do ask if you want more clarification or are running into issues.

Comment: Should i change all my object inside GlobalStyles separated and defined export one by one? Or is there an easier solution? In your example, i want `Name and Test` showing up in `Auto Import` not `testObject`

Comment: So if you wanted to access FontNormal from GlobalStyles you would start typing GlobalStyles, you'd get the auto import suggestion, then you'd add .FontNormal as with typical object access. The object is GlobalStyles and FontNormal is a Key inside that object.

Basically, you don't export / import Name and Test as from my example. You'd export / import testObject and access Name using testObject.Name.

Comment: so how does `react native` use `import {View, Text, Stylesheets, [etc]} from 'react-native'`, with the `View` using bracket sign? and you can see all available component using auto import. i think it's similar when i need to import my `key:value` using bracket sign, something like `import {FontNormal} from 'path/to/GlobalStyles.js'` and use `FontNormal` on-the-go instead of `import GlobalStyles from 'path/to/GlobalStyles.js'` and use `GlobalStyles.FontNormal` or maybe combining them like `import GlobalStyles, {FontNormal} from 'path/to/GlobalStyles.js'` and use it conditionally

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the mistake seems to be using dynamic export. That's old [CommonJs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) style. VSCode uses typescript tools for static analysis. To take advantage of that, you have to use [ES6 export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

CommonJs: `module.export={GlobalStyles}`

[ES6-modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules): `export GlobalStyles`

The significant difference between two is that CommonJs variant is simply variable which is defined at runtime. Ie. there is no way to know what you are exporting without executing the code. ES6 `export` is reserved word. It's construct which cant be changed after definition which also means, it's type definition can be found without actually executing the code.

Typescript, Babel etc provide interoperability between two module systems but they are two very different things by spec.